# How to parse complicated CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, escaping

I received a CSV file that includes a combination of string and tuple elements and cannot find a way to parse it properly. Am I missing something obvious?

csvfile

```
"presentation_id","presentation_name","sectionId","sectionNumber","courseId","courseIdentifier","courseName","activity_id","activity_prompt","activity_content","solution","event_timestamp","answer_id","answer","isCorrect","userid","firstname","lastname","email","role"
"26cc7957-5a6b-4bde-a996-dd823f54ece7","3-Axial Skeleton F18","937c47b0-cc66-4938-81de-1b1b58388499","001","3b5b5e49-1798-4eab-86d7-186cf59149b4","MOVESCI 230","Human Musculoskeletal Anatomy","62d059e8-9ab4-41d4-9eb8-00ba67d9fac9","A blow to which side of the knee might tear the medial collateral ligament?","{"choices":["medial","lateral"],"type":"MultipleChoice"}","{"solution":[1],"selectAll":false,"type":"MultipleChoice"}","2018-09-30 23:54:16.000","7b5048e5-7460-49f8-a64a-763b7f62d771","{"solution":[1],"type":"MultipleChoice"}","1","57ba970d-d02b-4a10-a64d-56f02336ee08","Student","One","student1@example.com","Student"
"26cc7957-5a6b-4bde-a996-dd823f54ece7","3-Axial Skeleton F18","937c47b0-cc66-4938-81de-1b1b58388499","001","3b5b5e49-1798-4eab-86d7-186cf59149b4","MOVESCI 230","Human Musculoskeletal Anatomy","f82cb32b-45ce-4d3a-aa74-b3fa1a1038a2","What is the name of this movement?","{"choices":["right rotation","left rotation","right lateral rotation","left lateral rotation"],"type":"MultipleChoice"}","{"solution":[1],"selectAll":false,"type":"MultipleChoice"}","2018-09-30 23:20:33.000","d6cce4d9-37ae-409e-afc5-54ad79f86226","{"solution":[3],"type":"MultipleChoice"}","0","921d1b9b-f550-4289-89f1-2a805b27eeb3","Student","Two","student2@example.com","Student"
```

where 1st row is titles, 2nd starts the data

```py
with open(filepathcsv) as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in readCSV:
        numcolumns = len(row)
        print(numcolumns,": ",row)
```

yields:

```
20 :  ['presentation_id', 'presentation_name', 'sectionId', 'sectionNumber', 'courseId', 'courseIdentifier', 'courseName', 'activity_id', 'activity_prompt', 'activity_content', 'solution', 'event_timestamp', 'answer_id', 'answer', 'isCorrect', 'userid', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'role']
25 :  ['26cc7957-5a6b-4bde-a996-dd823f54ece7', '3-Axial Skeleton F18', '937c47b0-cc66-4938-81de-1b1b58388499', '001', '3b5b5e49-1798-4eab-86d7-186cf59149b4', 'MOVESCI 230', 'Human Musculoskeletal Anatomy', '62d059e8-9ab4-41d4-9eb8-00ba67d9fac9', 'A blow to which side of the knee might tear the medial collateral ligament?', '{choices":["medial"', 'lateral]', 'type:"MultipleChoice"}"', '{solution":[1]', 'selectAll:false', 'type:"MultipleChoice"}"', '2018-09-30 23:54:16.000', '7b5048e5-7460-49f8-a64a-763b7f62d771', '{solution":[1]', 'type:"MultipleChoice"}"', '1', '57ba970d-d02b-4a10-a64d-56f02336ee08', 'William', 'Muter', 'wmuter@umich.edu', 'Student']
27 :  ['26cc7957-5a6b-4bde-a996-dd823f54ece7', '3-Axial Skeleton F18', '937c47b0-cc66-4938-81de-1b1b58388499', '001', '3b5b5e49-1798-4eab-86d7-186cf59149b4', 'MOVESCI 230', 'Human Musculoskeletal Anatomy', 'f82cb32b-45ce-4d3a-aa74-b3fa1a1038a2', 'What is the name of this movement?', '{choices":["right rotation"', 'left rotation', 'right lateral rotation', 'left lateral rotation]', 'type:"MultipleChoice"}"', '{solution":[1]', 'selectAll:false', 'type:"MultipleChoice"}"', '2018-09-30 23:20:33.000', 'd6cce4d9-37ae-409e-afc5-54ad79f86226', '{solution":[3]', 'type:"MultipleChoice"}"', '0', '921d1b9b-f550-4289-89f1-2a805b27eeb3', 'Noah', 'Willett', 'willettn@umich.edu', 'Student']
```

csv.reader is parsing each row differently because of complicated structure with embedded curly braced elements.

...but I expect **20** elements in each row.

Comment: The problem is the embedded `"` and `,`

Answer (score 0):

The in the records, not the code. Your code works fine. To solve the problem you need to fix csv file because the fields with json content weren't serialised correctly.

Just change one quote sign `"` to two signs `""` to escape them.

Here the example of fixed csv row.

```
"26cc7957-5a6b-4bde-a996-dd823f54ece7","3-Axial Skeleton F18","937c47b0-cc66-4938-81de-1b1b58388499","001","3b5b5e49-1798-4eab-86d7-186cf59149b4","MOVESCI 230","Human Musculoskeletal Anatomy","f82cb32b-45ce-4d3a-aa74-b3fa1a1038a2","What is the name of this movement?","{""choices"":[""right rotation"",""left rotation"",""right lateral rotation"",""left lateral rotation""],""type"":""MultipleChoice""}","{""solution"":[1],""selectAll"":false,""type"":""MultipleChoice""}","2018-09-30 23:20:33.000","d6cce4d9-37ae-409e-afc5-54ad79f86226","{""solution"":[3],""type"":""MultipleChoice""}","0","921d1b9b-f550-4289-89f1-2a805b27eeb3","Student","Two","student2@example.com","Student"
```

And the result of your code after fix:

```
20 :  ['26cc7957-5a6b-4bde-a996-dd823f54ece7', '3-Axial Skeleton F18', '937c47b0-cc66-4938-81de-1b1b58388499', '001', '3b5b5e49-1798-4eab-86d7-186cf59149b4', 'MOVESCI 230', 'Human Musculoskeletal Anatomy', 'f82cb32b-45ce-4d3a-aa74-b3fa1a1038a2', 'What is the name of this movement?', '{"choices":["right rotation","left rotation","right lateral rotation","left lateral rotation"],"type":"MultipleChoice"}', '{"solution":[1],"selectAll":false,"type":"MultipleChoice"}', '2018-09-30 23:20:33.000', 'd6cce4d9-37ae-409e-afc5-54ad79f86226', '{"solution":[3],"type":"MultipleChoice"}', '0', '921d1b9b-f550-4289-89f1-2a805b27eeb3', 'Student', 'Two', 'student2@example.com', 'Student']
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your suggestions!

Also, my apologies, as I did not include the raw CSV file I was trying to parse (example here:)

"b5ae18d3-b6dd-4d0a-84fe-7c43df472571"|"Climate_Rapid_Change_W18.pdf"|"18563b1e-a467-44b3-aed7-3607a1acd712"|"001"|"c86c8c8d-dca6-41cd-a010-a83e40d93e75"|"CLIMATE 102"|"Extreme Weather"|"278c4561-c834-4343-a770-3f544966f633"|"Which European city is at the same latitude as Ann Arbor?"|"{"choices":["Stockholm, Sweden","Berlin, Germany","London, England","Paris, France","Madrid, Spain"],"type":"MultipleChoice"}"|"{"solution":[4],"selectAll":false,"type":"MultipleChoice"}"|"2019-01-31 22:11:08.000"|"81392cd3-28e9-4e2e-8a33-018104b1f4d1"|"{"solution":[3,4],"type":"MultipleChoice"}"|"0"|"2db10c95-b507-4211-8244-394361148b22"|"Student"|"One"|"student1@umich.edu"|"Student"
"ee73fdaf-a926-4899-b0f7-9b942f1b44ad"|"6-Elbow, Wrist, Hand W19"|"48539109-529e-4359-83b9-2ae81be0532c"|"001"|"3b5b5e49-1798-4eab-86d7-186cf59149b4"|"MOVESCI 230"|"Human Musculoskeletal Anatomy"|"fcd7c673-d944-48c3-8a09-f458e03f8c44"|"What is the name of this movement?"|"{"choices":["first phalangeal joint","first proximal interphalangeal joint","first distal interphalangeal joint","first interphalangeal joint"],"type":"MultipleChoice"}"|"{"solution":[3],"selectAll":false,"type":"MultipleChoice"}"|"2019-01-31 22:07:32.000"|"9016f36c-41f5-4e14-84a9-78eea682c802"|"{"solution":[3],"type":"MultipleChoice"}"|"1"|"7184708d-4dc7-42e0-b1ea-4aca51f00fcd"|"Student"|"Two"|"student2@umich.edu"|"Student"

You are correct that the problem was the form of the CSV file.

1. I changed readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile) to readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="|", quotechar='|')
2. I then took the resulting list and removed the extraneous quotation marks from each element.

The rest of the program now works properly.